# Can you check my proof that $H$ is characteristic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $|G|=pm$,where $p\nmid m$. Then if $H\mathrel{\unlhd}G$ and $|H|=p$, than $H$ has to be characteristic.
We call a subgroup characteristic when $\varphi(T)\subset T$, $\forall \varphi \in Aut(G)$.

My proof:
Suppose $g\in \varphi(H)$ and $g \notin H$. Since $\varphi$ is bijective $|\varphi(H)|=|H|=p$. So $\langle g\rangle|p$ i.e. $\langle g\rangle =p$. Since $H$ is a normal group and $\langle g\rangle$ is another subgroup, $\langle g\rangle H$ is also subgroup of $G$. So $p^2||G|=pm$ which contradicts to the fact that $p\nmid m$.

Is the idea right? Which parts would you advice to fix?

Comment: This has been shown already [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/112116/normal-subgroup-of-prime-order-is-characteristic?rq=1).

Comment: I don't need a solution. I just wanted to know whether I did wrong or not.

Comment: OK, I see. Still, the solution there is answering your question too, because it shows the argument why $p^2$ would divide the order of $G$ (which was the discussion, see the answer below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all looks good, although you might want to elaborate on why $p^2 \mid |G|$, as this step was a little bigger than the rest of the steps in your argument.

Comment: $\langle g\rangle H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $|\langle g\rangle H|=p^2$, so $p^2=|\langle g\rangle H|||G|$. But why $|\langle g\rangle H|=p^2$ ? For brevity let me denote $\langle g\rangle$ by $A$. Sufficient to show that all elements of $ah$ type are different for different $a$ or $h$. Suppose $a_1h_1=a_2h_2$. Then $(a_2)^{-1}a_1=h_2(h_1)^{-1}$. But $A$ and $H$ have single common element $e$. So $a_1=a_2$ and $h_1=h_2$.

Do you mean this? Is everything right now?

Comment: Yes, that's good. But can you say why A and H have only a single common element?

Comment: Intersection of a subgroups is also a subgroup. Since order of intersection divides $p=|A|=|H|$, the order is 1.

Comment: Your questions really helped me to understand my own solution. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. To finish the argument, we just have to eliminate the possibility $|A \cap H|=p$: in that case we would have $|A|=|A \cap H|$, so that $A\cap H=A$, i.e., $A \subseteq H$. But since $g\in A$, this would contradict the assumption that $g\notin H$.